# My Django web page is not rendering models. How can i fix it?

Tags: python, django

I was learning Django but I got in some trouble, Please Help!
There is no error on either server or webpage.

My HomePage(index.html) is working fine but DetailPage(post.html) is rendering blank.

blog/views.py

```
from .models import Article
from django.views import generic


class HomePage(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    queryset = Article.objects.filter().order_by('date')
    context_object_name = 'Article_list'


class DetailPage(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'
    model = Article
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailPage.as_view(), name='detail')
]
```

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:200]
```

blog/templates/blog/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:10%">
{% for Article in Article_list %}
    <h1 align="center" style="padding-bottom:20px">
        <a href="{% url 'blog:detail' Article.id%}">{{Article.title}}</a>
    </h1>
    {{Article.date}}<br><br>
    {{Article.snippet}}...<br><hr>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

blog/templates/blog/post.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<h1>{{Article.body}}</h1>
{{Article.body}}<br>
{{Article.body}}
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: other elements of the webpage are rendering except Python variables i.e, {{Article.body}}, {{Article.body}},  {{Article.body}}

Answer (score 0):

Change `{{Article.body}}` to `{{object.body}}`

You haven't set `article` as a context in your `DetailView` so the template won't recognise article. If you wanted to use `article` instead of `object` you'd have to set it as context, but that's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Actually your method doesn't work for me. But changing {{ Article.title }} to {{ article.title }} worked for me but I don't know the concept behind it.